# Iterate Table produces single output instead of all files? (ModelBuilder, ArcGIS 10.1)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, iterator

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 and I would like to export attribute tables of my features stored in a geodatabase. I was following the post here to create the model: http://www.burdgis.com/blog/view/exporting-multiple-tables-from-a-geodatabase-using/. Only, instead of *Table to Excel* Tool, I used the *Table to Table*, as I want my output tables as .dbf. I have roughly 10 feature classes in my .gdb so I expect to get ~10 .DBF files back.

I have used *Inline model variable substitution*  **t_%Name%.dbf** (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000005w000000) to keep the names and all of my output tables.

However, as a result I've got back the single file, instead of all iterated features.

What am I doing wrong?

I don't see the difference between the posted model and mine:

[image]

Comment: What's the "Output Location" set to on your Table to Table operation? How many *.dbf tables exist in your geodatabase?

Comment: Try the 'Copy Rows' tool instead.

Comment: "Copy rows", when assigning "t_%Name%" as output table does not work neither. How can I control if my iteration worked well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Iteratively export polygon features attribute tables to .DBF files

My problem was easily solved by replacing **Iterate Tables** by **Iterate Features Classes**. 
However, my NEAR DISTANCE measures in attribute tables were not included in my exported .dbf files. 
I fixed this by suggestions of @jbalk :

I firstly copied my tables by **Copy Rows** (need to keep unique output by r_%Name% - "r_" could be modified of not included), and then exported them by **Table to Table** tool to my "output folder".

The **Iterate model** works great now !:)

[image]